# How can I search the first field of each line of a text file, and delete the whole line if a match is found

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

If and after the string is found in the first field of the text file, non case sensitive, the whole line is to be deleted. Have been stuck on this for a few days. The text file is 3 fields delimited by semicolons.

```
tput cup 17 0; echo "Enter a valid first name: "
tput cup 17 11; read personfirstName
tput cup 18 4; echo "Accept? (y)es
 or (n)o: "
tput cup 18 27; read Go
   if [ $Go = "y" ]
     then
       sed /$personfirstName/d  $personnelFile > f
         cp f $personnelFile
          rm f
    fi
```

Comment: There's a lot of code in your posting that has nothing to do with your statement problem. Maybe yoiu want `sed -i "/^$personfirstName;/i{;d;q}" file` or similar. Better to show just the minimum of small sample data, required output from same sample, your current output, your current code and any errMsgs. +1 for good formatting on your first Q. Good luck.

Comment: Use -i as a backup option too just to be on the safer side.  Try `sed -i.bak`, this will create a backup copy of updated files with .bak extension.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- If your version of `sed` supports the `-i` option, use that instead of sed/cp/rm commands.
- Use the `-e` option to specify the command you want to run.
- Use double-qoutes around arguments.
- Use your delimiter to avoid deleting "Jonny" when someone enters "Jon".

```
if [ $Go = "y" ]; then
    sed -i -e "/^$personfirstName;/d" "$personnelFile"
fi
```